# Denoting conjugate with a 5 or 6 pointed star -- which is more common?

Tags: math-mode

There are different notations in use for the complex conjugate. One notation is a superscript star. If one is using a star, is it more common to make it a 5-pointed star or a 6-pointed star?

A web search seems to show a 6-pointed star is more common, however, that's not conclusive.

I know `\star` makes a 5-pointed star and `\ast` makes a 6-pointed star.

EDIT: Thanks to everyone for your responses. I wish to emphasize that I want to find out what is, "in the wild," the more common form of star when a star is used to denote the complex conjugate. I'm thinking that's more nearly objective, in sense of not being tied to my personal preference.

Comment: I fear this is quite opinion-based. I for one (MSc mathematics student in Germany) have never seen it with `\star`, only with `\ast`.

Comment: If doubt gnaws at you, use `\overline{z}`.

Comment: @Fran but then you would worry whether to use `\bar{z}` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Every field in mathematics uses symbols in its own way. So a symbol in one field can have a different meaning to the reader in another field. You have to know the context.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is down to personal choice of the document and font author.

Neither LaTeX nor Unicode specify how many points there are. For example if you use `*` or `\ast` you get an asterisk associated with Unicode U+002A which just has name ASTERISK.

I looked at [wikipeda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk) to see if it said how many points an asterisk has and it helpfully clarifies the number as...

> In English, an asterisk is usually five- or six-pointed in sans-serif typefaces, six-pointed in serif typefaces, and six- or eight-pointed when handwritten.

`\star` is associated with U+22C6 which is STAR OPERATOR which similarly gives no hint about the shape.

U+22C6 `⋆` is specfically a math operator for binary relations so vertically centred on the math axis, like `+`

U+002A `*` is more complicated, LaTeX associates `*` and `\ast` to a binary operator with a vertically centred star shape, but many text fonts have a superscript character in that position so that a plain text C*  corresponds to TeX `C^{*}` not `C*`

Other Unicode slots are more specific,

U+2726 ✦  is BLACK FOUR POINTED STAR

U+2734 ✴ is EIGHT POINTED BLACK STAR

Answer (score 0):

The usage of each symbol may vary depending on the specific context.

In general, the `\ast` symbol is commonly used to denote **multiplication operations** in various fields of mathematics, including *algebra*, *analysis*, and *geometry*. For example, in *algebra*, we can use the `\ast` symbol to denote the *multiplication operation in a ring or group*. In *analysis*, the `\ast` symbol is often used to denote *convolution*, while in *geometry*, the `\ast` symbol can be used to denote the *cross product*.

On the other hand, the `\star` symbol is more commonly used as a generic symbol to denote a **binary operation**, which is a function that combines two elements to produce a third element. For example, we can use the `\star` symbol to denote a generic operation on a set A, as mentioned earlier. Additionally, the `\star` symbol can be used in other areas of mathematics, such as in *graph theory* to denote the *transitive closure* of a graph.

In summary, the main difference between the usage of the `\ast` and `\star` symbols in mathematics is that `\ast` is more commonly used to denote **multiplication operations**, while `\star` is more commonly used as a generic symbol to denote a **binary operation**. However, the choice of one symbol over the other may depend on the specific context and convention.

As the complex conjugate involves the multiplication of two quantities, the notation `\ast` is a natural choice to denote the **complex conjugate**, instead of `\star`. Additionally, it is a convention widely adopted in mathematical and physical literature, which makes the notation more consistent and easy to understand. Therefore, the use of the `\ast` notation to denote complex conjugates is justified by the convention and mathematical context in which this operation is defined.